# ; expected c# transfer and carry big string VS2012

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, string-concatenation, sqlcommand

I have

```
CmdString = "insert into Team_table (name1, name2, result1, result2) (select t1.name,t2.name,NULL,NULL from teams t2 cross join teams t1)";
```

Whene I divide it in 2 columns by presssiin enter like

```
CmdString = "insert into Team_table (name1, name2, result1, result2) 
(select t1.name,t2.name,NULL,NULL from teams t2 cross join teams t1)";
```

errore appears

How can I solve that?

Comment: `errore appears` and the error is...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@` symbol in front of the string , then you can break the string on multiple lines

```
string CmdString = @"insert into Team_table (name1, name2, result1, result2) 
                (select t1.name,t2.name,NULL,NULL from teams t2 cross join teams t1)";
```

The reason you are getting the error is because the compiler is considering new line as a new C# statement, and it is expecting you to close the previous  string and terminate the statement using `;`

EDIT: As [@Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) has pointed out, making it a verbatim string *(with @)* would result in the new line character to be part of string. So your string would be something like:

`"insert into Team_table (name1, name2, result1, result2) \r\n                 (select t1.name,t2.name,NULL,NULL from teams t2 cross join teams t1)"`

If you don't want the line break and want to split string on multiple lines, then you have to define a single string on each line and use concatenation like:

```
string CmdString = 
    "insert into Team_table (name1, name2, result1, result2) " + 
    "(select t1.name,t2.name,NULL,NULL from teams t2 cross join teams t1)";
```

Comment: Then the newline is in the string itself; that may or may not be intended.

Comment: @Servy Being a T-SQL statement I don't think newlines/whitespace will have any side effects.

Comment: @Servy, the string seems like a SQL statement, I am sure an empty line  will not have an effect.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Perhaps, but the author should still be aware that of what's happening; the question need not be localized to the specific case of SQL anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Try following

```
CmdString = "insert into Team_table (name1, name2, result1, result2)" + 
" (select t1.name,t2.name,NULL,NULL from teams t2 cross join teams t1)";
```

or

```
CmdString = @"insert into Team_table (name1, name2, result1, result2) 
(select t1.name,t2.name,NULL,NULL from teams t2 cross join teams t1)";
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this.

```
    CmdString = "insert into Team_table (name1, name2, result1, result2)" + 
        "(select t1.name,t2.name,NULL,NULL from teams t2 cross join teams t1)";
```